# cross origin login in satellizer Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, satellizer

I am using [**Satellizer**](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) for JWT authentication in front end.I have my server side **Node js** deployed at [Cloud9](http://c9.io/) and client side running on localhost.Now **CORS** are enabled on server side through cors module and working fine.

Same client side uses Restangular as service.

```
 RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('//another domain's link here');
    RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
  selfLink: "_links.self.href"
});

 RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
```

Now this is working fine.every request through Restangular is successful in node.but i can't login or signup.request cannot access server side.and there is no error in console too.i have tried  [this issue](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/issues/348)  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299297/angularjs-satellizer-jwt-cors-issue-when-authenticated)  and many others.but cannot get it working.

So how i can make satellizer working for cross domain????

**Edit:** Additionally on adding this code in satellizer.

```
 return $http(opts)
       .success(function(response) {
               alert("success");
               console.log(response);
        shared.setToken(response);
          return response;
      })
      .error(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
               alert("error");                 
       })
       .catch(function(resp){
           console.log(resp);
           alert("catching error");
       });
```

I got error block with null in console and also catch block is invoked with status:-1.

[image]

Comment: Are you found decision of this problem?

Comment: no can't find any solution..